# Is it possible to act with svg as with glyphicon?

Tags: html, svg, glyphicons, inline-svg

Is it possible to act with svg as with glyphicon in HTML?

I mean to make inline svg scale to current font-size and may be use current color/background-color?

**Afterword:** it is possible to manipulate "svg-glyph" size with "1em" but be ready that 1 em is a little bit inadequate value: it is bigger then capital letter and smaller then line height.

```css
span { 
  fill:gold;
  font-size:24px;
  color: green;
  background-color: Lavender;
}

span > svg { 
   display:inline-block;

   width:1em;  
}
```

```html
<div>
<span>
    1 em Baseline Align: 
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="vertical-align:baseline">
    <rect height="100" width="100"        fill="none" stroke="currentColor"  stroke-width="15" />
   </svg>
</span>
</div>

<div>
<span>
1 em Text bottom Align: 
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="vertical-align:text-bottom">
    <rect height="100" width="100"  fill="none" stroke="currentColor"  stroke-width="15" />
   </svg>
</span>
</div>

<div>
<span>
0.75em Baseline Align: 
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="vertical-align:Baseline; width:0.75em; height:0.75em;">
    <rect height="100" width="100"  fill="none" stroke="currentColor"  stroke-width="20" />
   </svg>
</span>
</div>
```

Somehow should be possible to inherit fill and viewport from html but I can't find how.

P.S. It should be possible  with javascript but let stay with no javascript solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaling to current font-size is quite simple - em units.

And fill/stroke are inheritable CSS properties by default:

```css
span { 
  fill:gold;
  font-size:24px;
}

span > svg { 
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:middle;
   width:1em;  
}
```

```html
<span>
Text: 
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
</svg>
 </span>
```

**Inheriting text color**

To have your SVG use the same colour as the text, use the special colour value "currentColor".

```css
span { 
  color:gold;
  font-size:24px;
}

span > svg { 
   height:1em;  
}
```

```html
<span>
Text: 
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="currentColor" />
</svg>
and more text
 </span>
```

Comment: Thank you! And thank you twice for idea to use snippet. But I do not see that fill/stroke are inheritable. Could you check the snippet inside my qyestion? There stroke do not use green.

Comment: I added an example showing how to inherit the text colour into the SVG.